# Django ORM: misleading `first()` for `prefetch_related`

Tags: python, django, django-orm

Working on a DRF endpoint I expierenced an issue with `prefetch_related` and `first` called on the prefetched set. Let's consider two models: `X` and `Y`; `Y` contains a foreign key to `X`.

Then I perform following code:

```
qs = X.objects.all().prefetch_related("y_set")

for x in qs:
    for y in x.y_set.all():
        print(e)
```

Everything is OK, django performs 2 queries as expected.

Then I perform:

```
for x in qs:
    for y in x.y_set.all():
        print(e)
    first = x.y_set.first()
```

In this example, Django perform n+2 queries what is not expected (at least for me).

I found a workaround with:

```
for x in qs:
    for y in x.y_set.all():
        print(e)
    first = y_set.all()[0] if y_set.all() else None
```

but it's not satisfying for me - I feel like checking if `qs` is not empty and then taking the first element is a bit messy, I'd definitely prefer to use `first` or some other function that hides this logic.

Can anyone explain why `first` doesn't use prefetched cache or can you give me a tip how to handle it a bit clearer? (I don't want to add a wrapper to handle that, I prefer native django orm solution. Also I can't just take the first element from the loop - I simplified the example a lot)

Comment: `first` makes a query using the `LIMIT` clause in SQL, hence it is a different query, (Fetching all objects to get only the first one would be inefficient, hence the `LIMIT` clause is used)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yup, it makes sense but in this case we have all data in the cache so why Django can't simply take it? I believe it's much more effective. As it's an edge-case it may be simply not implemented but I'm not sure if there is any other reason why it is not done.

Answer (score 2):

`.first()` basically uses the `LIMIT` clause in SQL to get the first object of a query. So when one calls `queryset.first()` it naturally makes a separate query.

You further ask that since the queryset is already present in memory why doesn't `.first()` simply use that evaluate queryset? Well let me put it this way:

It is quite common to chain methods on a queryset `.annotate(...).filter(...)` etc. and we can do things like:

```
queryset = SomeModel.objects.all()
for object in queryset:
    print(object)
queryset2 = list(queryset.filter(a=1))
```

Here we expect `queryset2` to make a *different* query to the database instead of perhaps filtering the objects at the python level because for some reason the database itself might have new entries or perhaps we may even be making some annotations instead of the simply calling `.filter()` so we **want** this to be a separate query. This in essence is the same reason `.first()` will not simply use the prefetched objects.

Comment: Looking at the source code of `first()`, if the queryset is not ordered, then it also executes an `order_by()` which is another reason why it performs another query.

https://github.com/django/django/blob/06c50cee0fb1fd23248518334eabb2fbf61b2cbc/django/db/models/query.py#L683

Here's the related ticket in Django's issue tracker:
https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/23805